# Why parameterised data type declaration in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, instance, type-parameter

I went through a you-tube video and learnt that the person declared a new data type using parameterised data type as :

```
data Quad a = Quad a a a a
instance  (Show a) => Show (Quad a) where
show (Quad a b c d) = (show a) ++ " " ++  -- code continues for printing
```

My doubt is why do we need the first line of the code. I did something like this and it still works.
My code :

```
data Q = Q Integer Integer Integer Integer 
instance  Show Q where
show (Q a b c d) = (show a)++" " ++ --code continues for printing
```

What is the use of the first line namely `data Quad a = Quad a a a a` , when instead we can do it by my method as shown just above ? Please Help. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how familiar you are with imperative programming languages like Java, but I will assume that you are familiar with *generics*. Now your defintion of `Q` would be - more or less - equivalent to something in Java like:

```java
public class Q {

    private Integer field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private Integer field3;
    private Integer field4;

    public Q (Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3, Integer field4) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
    }

}
```

(yeah I know `Integer` in Java is not equivalent to `Integer` in Haskell, but that's not an issue here).

Now this thus limits us to working with `int`s. A problem might occur what to do in case we want a *quaternion* with `double`s, or `Car`s. So that won't work very effectively.

The original definition of `Quad` however would be something in Java like:

```java
public class Quad<A> {

    private A field1;
    private A field2;
    private A field3;
    private A field4;

    public Quad (A field1, A field2, A field3, A field4) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
        this.field4 = field4;
    }

}
```

So you can work with a `Quad<Integer>` which is - more or less - equivalent to the above definition of `Q`. But I can easily work with `Quad<Double>` and `Quad<Car>` to construct quaternions of doubles, cars, horses,...

Now you might think that a quaternion of horses does not make any sense. Quaternions are usually indeed specified over numbers. But there are several data structures to represent numbers: `Integer`s can - as the name suggest - only represent integral values. Perhaps you want to allow `Double`s as well. Furthermore `Integer` can represent *all* integral values (until the memory is exhausted). Although that's of course a nice feature, it comes with a cost: performance. It usually takes more time to do computations on `Integer`s (even if they have the *same* value). So if you want to boost performance, you may look for `Quad Int16` for instance.

By using a type parameter you allow yourself a form of flexibility: you do not have to define a data type that looks almost the same as another one.

Furthermore you can define - like the Youtube lessons shows - type instances where you put constraints on the `a`. So for all `Quad a`s where `a` can be `show`ed, then you can show the `Quad a`. You can also put constraints on functions. Say for instance you want to provide a way to calculate the sum of the "elements" of the quad. You can define:

```
sumquad :: Num a => Quad a -> a
sumquad (Q x y z t) = x + y + z + t
```

So now you have defined a `sumquad` function for *all* `Quad a` types where `a` is an instance of the `Num` typeclass (and thus supports addition). If we would work with `Q`, there should be a `sumquadQ` for `Q`, a `sumquadQDouble` for `QDouble` (a hypothetical `data QDouble = QDouble Double Double Double Double`), etc. So it would require a large amount of work and would result in less elegant code.

Comment: Thanks, great help !

Answer (score 3):

`Quad a a a a` allows you to create a quad containing any type whereas `Q Integer Integer Integer Integer` only allows Integers.

So it depends on what your quad should be able to store. If you only store Integers maybe it should be called IntegerQuad. One reason might be that you want to implement a function like

```
--collapse :: Q -> Integer
collapse Q(a,b,c,d) = a+b+c+d
```

Which you cant do with a unless (+) is specified.

In Haskell I believe that you should go as abstract as you can since that gives you the most flexibility and the most likely that you can reuse other functions.